# Can i use one developer account with multiple AdMob accounts?

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I have one google developer account. Can I use multiple AdMob accounts with the google developer account?

For example:
I have 20 applications
5 applications using one AdMob pub id
5 applications using another AdMob pub id
5 applications using a 3rd AdMob pub id
5 applications using a 4th AdMob pub id
etc...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish your application with Two Different account but for that you need to set Unique package name for your both application.
For application A if you choose com.xyz you can not use it for application B.
And as you have two application with Different package name you must register each separately for admob.

And I.E.

1.Can I use single admob publisher id in multiple application. Will that create any problem or I have to create separate publisher id for each app.

You can use the same id for each app.

2.If I want to create 5 android apps using google places api do I need to create 5 google places api key or I can use single key in all app.

You only need one api key.

Comment: actually, i want to ask that, my application is already diffrent package name, they are already different applications.My question is that  if i have two diffrent developer accounts , can i use one admob account?

Answer (score 0):

It’s risky. Saying from experience,  Google may ban both of your accounts.